# Substitute s in transfer function

Tags: matlab, transfer

I need to substitute a value for `s` in a transfer function. For example:

```
G(s)= 1/ (s+3)
```

I need to substitute

```
s = -2.118 +2.221j
```

What code should I use for this?

PS: Unfortunately, I only have control system toolbox in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with saving m-file with

```
 function g = transferFun( s )
 g = 1 ./ ( s + 3 )
```

And then calling the function

```
 >> transferFun( -2.118 + 2.221*j )
```

Comment: Thankyou Shai..but it doesnt seem to work. Is there any other option

Comment: @Anu - what do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? do you get an error? not the expected results? you'll have to provide more details and information in order to get reasonable answers here...

Comment: @Anu Make sure your m file is called `transferFun.m`

Comment: @Shai.. Thankyou. I renamed the m file to transferFun.m Its perfectly working.

Comment: @Anu I'm glad this works for you. Feel free to "accept" this answer by clicking the "V" icon beside it.

Answer (score 1):

As shai mentioned you can simply create an m file with the function.

However, if you are just doing some quick calculations here is a way to just do it on the command line. You can define an anonymous function like this:

```
 G = @(s) 1/(s+3)
```

Now you can simply call it like this:

```
G(-2.118 +2.221j)
```

Note that Matlab is case sensitive.

Comment: I would use './' in `G` in case @Anu decides he wants `s` to be a vector... Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Shai I agree that using `./` would be more robust, but that is more a comment to the question. This is the most straightforward implementation of the given function.